# What is the meaning of this joke?

Tags: jokes

[Behold the joke in its original glory](https://youtu.be/mI3Me2Cf2Mw?si=6QRQYPNCAdXISFTM&t=5486)

The judge looked down upon the counsel and said,

Judge: Listen, counsel. I have been listening to you for three hours, and I am none the wiser.

Barrister: I expected that, my lord, but I thought you might be better informed.

How is "I thought you might be better informed" a jab at the judge?

Comment: [YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/articles/knowledge-wisdom-understanding) has an article (comprehensive if somewhat less than crystal clear at times) comparing/contrasting knowledge, understanding and wisdom. I heard a fine Bible teacher, Huw (I think that's how his name is spelled) Thompson (I remember his joke about the silent _p_) state this: << Knowledge is knowing _what_ (basic facts), understanding is knowing _why_ (things are as they are, and their interrelations), and wisdom is knowing _how_ (to make sound judgements, effect good changes).>> Bloom's taxonomy adds detail.

Comment: If there's a "joke" here, it falls flat on me. But what the barrister says is (at least in principle) *ambiguous*. He may mean *I thought you would have had better background knowledge which would enable you to understand what I've been saying.* But that's made less likely by preceding *I expected that* (if that was the case, why didn't he explain things in a way that *didn't* require that background knowledge?). The alternative reading is *I though it better (I thought it would be a good idea) to try and give you more information, even though you may have been unable to take it all in*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because explaining jokes is off topic.

Answer (score 6):

It is a simple play on usage.  The word 'wise' has as its first definition in the Cambridge English Dictionary as

> B2 (*approving*) having or showing the ability to make good judgments, based on a deep understanding and experience of life:

The noun *wisdom* unequivocally refers a quality of sense and understanding.  In CED:-

> the ability to use your knowledge and experience to make good decisions and judgments

But the phrase *being none the wiser* or *being wise to something * relates to possessing information about something.

So the joke here involved what the French call a *double-entendre*.  The judge is saying that he is no better informed than be was before the barrister started speaking.  The barrister hits back by taking the word 'wiser' in the 'wisdom' sense of 'wiser'.

I would not recommend this type of insult in an actual court of law.  The play on language is not an amusing witty 'dig':  it is downright rude (a 'contempt', in effect).  On the stage, however, the barrister safe and gets a laugh from the audience.

Comment: You are probably right, but would people easily get this nuance, and laugh?

Comment: @Gio They apparently did in the video.

Comment: @Gio - I did, and I did the first time I heard it. It even got a bit of a chuckle just now. If your audience likes word play it'll go down well but some might be left scratching their heads (always the risk with any joke).

Comment: I can well imagine John Cleese perpetrating this on _Python_.

Comment: @Gio I found it *very* funny and laughed out loud when I read it

Answer (score 0):

He is basically calling the judge dumb (the opposite of wise) because he wasn't expecting him to be "wiser" at the end of his long argument, he was expecting him to be just as dumb but to at least have the information in his mind.

Answer (score -1):

The judge says "I'm none the wiser" which is a phrase meaning they're not convinced by the argument or don't understand what they other person is trying to say.

The reply is funny because the first part intentionally interprets the word "wiser" in a more literal sense (as in "yeah, I can see that you're not any wiser").

The second part of the reply is then an insinuation that despite the judge not becoming any wiser, the barrister at least assumed the judge would understand what was being said, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Hello, neptun. Does this really add anything to Tuffy's answer?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I haven't read it properly, but it looks like they're trying to something similar to what I said but in a more obtuse way.

Comment: I don't see how "I'm none the wiser" can imply *I'm not convinced* (by some argument put forward by the barrister). But I can certainly imagine it being said if the barrister was trying to convince the judge of his client's innocence, if the judge was completely unable to *understand* the barrister's argument (if you don't understand an argument, you probably can't be "convinced" by it);

Comment: Hello @FumbleFingers as you point out, it's difficult to be convinced by an argument you don't fully understand. That's exactly the point.

Comment: In many court cases there's no reason to suppose the judge needs to be "convinced" of anything at all. Often his only role is to make sure procedures are properly followed, so a ***jury*** can be "convinced" by either counsel for the defense or counsel for the prosecution. Nothing I see in the question text suggests to me that there's no jury, so I see no reason to suppose the judge needed convincing. And certainly nothing about saying *I'm none the wiser* implies anything about being convinced.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If someone presents an argument, and you say "I'm not convinced", it doesn't mean that you think the argument is wrong, but that you think something is missing to make it complete. When I wrote "not convinced by **or** don't understand the argument", it is a description of that spectrum between not finding the argument complete and not even understanding the argument. Without knowing what they talked about prior, it's not possible to know where in that the spectrum the judge is at when they say they're "none the wiser" about it.

Comment: I don't understand any of that. So far as I'm concerned there's no inherent connection between saying "I'm none the wiser" and having someone trying to *persuade* you of something. The implication is that you wanted information but didn't get it, not that you were inviting someone to convince you of anything. But let's just leave it at that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The situation is that the judge is presented with something that they are supposed to make a decision about, and they don't find the the information convincing enough to make an informed decision about it. You seem stuck on "convincing" having to do with persuading someone with an opinion rather than convincing as in "clear and convincing evidence". But you also keep ignoring the "or" in the sentence so this is not really going anywhere.